# Midi import into GarageBand

Tags: garageband

I recorded a midi file on my electric piano. When I import it into GarageBand, the tempo is changed and the instrument tracks sound different. The music sounds terrible after being converted into GarageBand. How do I get the same sound in GarageBand that I am hearing on my electric piano?

Comment: When you use midi to record into Garageband it has to use it's own patches (voices). If you record from your keyboard using a standard line-out/in then your keyboard sound will be the same. However, the Garageband pianos seem pretty decent - but certainly not Ivory II. Would it be possible to record directly to Garageband via USB or an actual Midi to USB setup?

Comment: What are you using to record a midi file from your electric piano?